# How to translate "A moment in my arms, a lifetime in my heart" for a tattoo?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

I’m in need of some help with a translation from English to Latin. 
I’m in the middle of designing a tattoo and the client wants the sentence
 ‘A moment in my arms, a lifetime in my heart’ 
to be written in Latin and has sent over the sentence
 ‘momento in arma mea vita, meum cor’ 
but has used Google Translate to swap the English to Latin (and we all know how Google Translate likes to butcher translations). I would greatly appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: I'll write up a proper answer later, but first and foremost: that translation is, as you quite rightly surmised, nonsense. It literally means something like "[I give] my heart to the momentum inside my life weapons".

Comment: Will you tell us the placement of the tattoo?  That might have some impact on the appropriate choice of words.

Comment: Un momento en mis brazos y toda la vida en mi corazón.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're quite right not to trust Google Translate! The sentence it gave you is nonsense.

A "moment" in Latin is either a *punctum* or a *momentum*; out of the two, I like *punctum* better. (*Punctum* comes from the word for pricking something with a pin, while *momentum* comes from a word for movement and motion, if that affects anything.) It's often found in the slightly longer phrase *punctum temporis* "moment of time", but in context it could be understood without that.

A "lifetime", as in a long span of time, would be a *saeculum* rather than a *vita*. (A *vita* is literally a "life", but it's more like a biography or a living soul than a span of time.) This can mean literally a human lifetime, or figuratively a generation, or figuratively a hundred years (which the Romans considered something like the maximum possible lifetime).

One standard word for "arms" is *bracchia*; Vergil and Ovid use this word when talking about embraces, so it seems good for your purpose. And "heart" is straightforwardly *cor*, both literally and metaphorically.

Putting it all together, with appropriate endings on the words: *punctum in bracchiis [meis], saeculum in corde [meo]*. You can swap in *momentum* if you like it better without changing the overall meaning. The *meis* and *meo* literally mean "my", but can be left off here where the context makes the meaning clear; leaving them off makes it a bit shorter and cleaner.

Comment: Can't you dispense with the "in"s also, and interpret brachiis and corde as locatives?  Or at least for "corde"?  Locative maybe isn't quite right for the use of "brachiis" in this sentence

Comment: @CMonsour Maybe, but to me the locative doesn't sound right for these nouns; I'm only used to it with place names and a few special words.

Comment: Normally a lifetime is aetas. Saeculum means an "age" like an age of civilization.

Comment: Also, I hate to be a nudge, but if a Roman read your phrase, he would first think you were talking about something in the branches of trees. Although we say we hold someone "in our arms", that is not the way the Romans thought about a hug or embrace. In Virgil it says *collo dare bracchia circum* (to throw the arms around the neck), but that is a completely different expression that does not use the word *in*.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Tyler Durden's answer, I'd go with:

> **paulisper in sinu
>
> perpetuo in pectore**

This very literally translates to:

> briefly in the lap
> forever in the chest

Which is less literal than Draconis' answer but I think captures the sentiment.

**paulisper**: There are a lot of words that mean 'briefly', and the two most common ones are probably *parumper* and *paulisper*. I went with *paulisper* purely because *parumper* sounds kind of goofy when an anglophone says it, which I don't think is the vibe we were going for.

**in sinu**: A *sinus* is fundamentally a curved surface and by extension a whole lot of things, including a person's lap or their bosom (cf. *gremium*, which also means lap or bosom), particularly when it provides shelter. It's a good choice.

**perpetuo**: Primarily means 'constantly' but also by extension 'forever'. Some other adverb could have been chosen but this works, and it alliterates with *paulisper*.

**in pectore**: *Pectus* is literally 'chest', but the chest was the seat of emotion to the Romans. *Cor* 'heart' was also used (so you could use *in corde*), but I like the contrast of *in sinu*, with a figurative chest used fairly literally, with *in pectore*, with a literal chest used figuratively. (There is no scope for confusion: *sinus* is not used for the chest as the seat of emotion.)

I would not explicitly express "my"; it's implied.

Answer (score -2):

This question is probably long dead, but it got some activity so I guess there is some interest in it.

A lifetime in Latin is *aetas*. The way you say someone is in your arms is *in sinu*, or sometimes just *sinu* poetically. When you talk about something happening for a moment in Latin, the word *brevis* is used, or sometimes *parumper* but that word is too long for a tatoo, and we probably want an adverb anyway, so *brevis* might be not perfect either. Especially given the romantic tone, maybe the appropriate word is *paulum*.

To connect your two clauses, you would not use *sed* (but except), but would instead should use *vero* which is used when the clauses are opposite to each  in a symmetric way, especially emphatically, which is what we have here.

To say "in my heart" there is *mi in pectore* or *in corde*. Ovid wrote *in corde meo* but also *meo pectore* in the *Amores*. In the *Tristia* he used the poetic plural *pectoribus*.

**Paulum Sinu Meo

   Vero

Aetas Corde Meo**

This means, "A moment in my arms, but a lifetime in my heart." The *vero* can be omitted, but I think in this expression it gives it more power and emphasizes the antithesis of the couplet. I have omitted the preposition *in* to narrow the lines, but you can use *in Sinu* and *in Corde*, if desired.

Note that if you want the shortest possible expression, you can write *Paulum Sinu Aetas Corde* and the meaning is still captured.

(Note on vero: this is modern usage typically seen in mottoes, as below:

*Innixus vero Validus* (not supported, but standing strong)
   motto of the Lyons family in Ireland

*Spiritus promptus vero  caro infirma* (The spirit is willing, but the flesh is weak)
   popular paraphrase of the Vulgate

Comment: *Vero* in the sense that can sometimes be translated as 'but' is an adverb, not a conjunction, and isn't used like that. It's more helpful to think of it as 'however'; it's effectively a postpositive particle.

Comment: @Cairnarvon In mottoes and short sayings in modern Latin sometimes vero is not postpositive, but treated as a more normal conjunction. Although it could be argued it is improper, in mottoes it is not unusual for the rules to be bent. I added a couple of examples to my answer.

Comment: *Innixus vero validus* means 'supported by truth, strong'; *vero* is an instrumental ablative of the noun *verum* and the *in-* isn't privative. *Spiritus promptus vero caro infirma* is wrong; the actual phrase (and the title of the Dali painting) is *Spiritus promptus est, caro vero infirma*, with *vero* in the correct position.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Hmm, ok, would you rather her tatoo read Paulum Sinu Meo Aetas Vero Corde Meo?

Comment: No, it's too strongly adversative and you really don't need it at all. I'd personally go asyndetically with *Paulisper in sinu / perpetuo in pectore*, probably; *paulum* without further determiners means 'a little' in terms of quantity, not time, and *aetas* is just a noun in the nominative (*aetatem*, as an accusative of duration, would be better, but I'd read it as 'for a lifetime' rather than 'forever' first). I'd omit the *meo* as implied but not the *in* for clarity.

Comment: @Cairnarvon You should post that as an answer.